# Showing serial terms using the complex bit masks

Tags: c#

I need to make a method for displaying serial terms based on the number associated with these days.

So, I base myself for each day (term), set a specific number.

> Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tues = 4, Wed = 8, Thu = 16, Fri = 32, Sat = 64

If the user has chosen all eg working days, Mon - Fri  = 62,
or weekend Sat - Sun = 65.

I have to start the method to show each week for those days of that term.

current code to display the term in the calendar

```
        var terminDates = dataAccess.GetTerminDate(personal.LPE_Nr, date, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));

        for (int i = 0; i < terminDates.Count; i++)
        {
            T_TERMINE _TERMINE = new T_TERMINE();
            List<T_TERMINE> terminList = dataAccess.GetListTermins(personal.LPE_Nr, terminDates[i]);
            string serId = null;
            foreach (var termin in terminList)
            {
                _TERMINE.TER_Betreff = termin.TER_Betreff;
                _TERMINE.TER_ID = termin.TER_ID;
                serId = termin.TER_TRS_ID;
            }
            List<T_TERMINSERIE> serieTermins = dataAccess.GetSerieTermins(serId);
            T_TERMINSERIE _TERMINSERIE = new T_TERMINSERIE();
            foreach (var ser_termin in serieTermins)
            {
                _TERMINSERIE.TRS_StartZeit = ser_termin.TRS_StartZeit;
                _TERMINSERIE.TRS_EndZeit = ser_termin.TRS_EndZeit;
                _TERMINSERIE.TRS_TagWoche = ser_termin.TRS_TagWoche; //(16)here I get the number of the bit of the mask
                _TERMINSERIE.TRS_StartDatum = ser_termin.TRS_StartDatum;
            }
           /* how now to include method to make that custom event appear 
            whenever the method renders, me now CustomEvent is only 
           displayed for the first time, how to include it and Event for each time the method finds that day in a single week?*/
           //FindNextDay()?
            CustomEvent ce = new CustomEvent() { IgnoreTimeComponent = true,
                Date = terminDates[i],
                EventText = _TERMINE.TER_Betreff,
                EventColor = Color.BlueViolet };
            if (!generatedEvents.Any(x => x.Date == ce.Date))
            {
                calendar1.AddEvent(ce);
                generatedEvents.Add(ce);
            }
        }
```

Now the most important is the method that will be based on the number I will be reading from the base, I mean numbers in the enum.
Repeat this term for every week.

```
   [Flags]
        enum DaysBitMask { Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tues = 4, Wed = 8, Thu = 16, Fri = 32, Sat = 64 }
        static DayOfWeek FindNextDay(DaysBitMask mask, DayOfWeek currentDay)
        {
            DayOfWeek dayCursor = currentDay;
            int counter = 0;
            do
            {
                int cursorMask = 0x01 << (int)dayCursor;
                int operationResult = (cursorMask & (int)mask);
                if (operationResult > 0)
                    return dayCursor;

                dayCursor = (DayOfWeek)(((int)dayCursor + 1) % 7);
                counter++;
            }
            while (counter < 7);

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong flow. We shouldn't be here");
        }
```

This is my currently designed code, which does not work, please if you can correct my method "FindNextDay" and tell me how to apply it to get to the correct display of the term. Thank you all for the time.

Comment: What is wrong with you `FindNextDay` method?

Comment: @RomanKoliada Right, I need to find one week on this day

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what `FindNextDay` is meant to do; can you give example desired inputs and outputs?

Comment: @steve16351 I want that if the term is set for Thursday 9.05, (daysBit Mask (Thursday = 16)), I want to repeat it for 16.05, 23.05..

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it - you pass `currentDay` as a `DayOfWeek`, but how can you tell "the next Thursday" from that - shouldn't it be a `DateTime`?

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to achieve. I think you'd better add an example of input and output you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
    [Flags]
    enum DaysBitMask { Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tues = 4, Wed = 8, Thu = 16, Fri = 32, Sat = 64 }

    static DayOfWeek FindNextDay(DaysBitMask mask, DayOfWeek currentDay)
    {
        DayOfWeek dayCursor = currentDay;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++)
        {
            int cursorMask = 0x01 << (int)dayCursor;
            int operationResult = (cursorMask & (int)mask);
            if (operationResult > 0)
                return dayCursor;

            dayCursor = (DayOfWeek)(((int)dayCursor + 1) % 7);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("We shouldn't be here");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. how can I then display this method for every new event? I take from the base always only for the DaysBitMask number, I changed my code.

Comment: @lasta, I'm not sure I'm following the idea. I also don't see any case in the code where you use FindNextDay method.

Comment: The problem with me is the use of the method itself, because I take values from the database for the days, these are the same values that are in the DaysBitMask enum. Is it an example of how I could invite this method to set the term as the first one for each time it finds a new day.

Comment: I don't understand the idea then. The method you've designed is to get the next day of week based on the current day of week and the mask (with days of week also). I don't see any reasons why this method should be used to solve the task you have (wich is about working with dates, not days of week).

Comment: I corrected the code, I wrote in the comment I needed